# eMail Client Compatible with Yahoomail

Tags: thunderbird

Is there any email client that can be configured with yahoomail?  Or do we know of any trick that can be used to make it work with Thunderbird?

Comment: I use Thunderbird for all my 10 mail accounts, none of which are yahoo. I just tried adding a spoof yahoo account and apart from rejecting it because of the username, it set up OK as a POP3 and SMTP with SSL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any email client that supports IMAP (which is all of them) can be setup to use Yahoo Mail. Just use the following settings when adding a new account to your email client...

```
Incoming Server: imap.mail.yahoo.com
Outgoing Server: smtp.mail.yahoo.com
Incoming Port: 993 with SSL
Outgoing Port: 465 with SSL or port 587 with SSL/TLS
-It is necessary to enable SSL or TLS for Outgoing SMTP port.
Username: full email address (for example, free2rhyme@yahoo.com)
Password: the password you use to sign in to your Yahoo! Account
```

Comment: I tried it with Sylpheed Version 3.4.0beta5 (Build 1149). It can't receive Yahoo mail. Nothing is written in log window. Sending works OK. I have configured another IMAP account with it, and it receives fine.

Comment: I could get messages in Sylpheed after I right-clicked on the account on the left column and chose "Rebuild folder tree".

Answer (score 0):

You can use thunderbird. It can be configured for yahoo mail.

Use these settings:

Incoming Server: imap.mail.yahoo.com
Outgoing Server: smtp.mail.yahoo.com

and set it up.

Answer (score 0):

Geary is a nice simple email client that supports yahoo mail without needing to know the details of IMAP. During setup, you will just need to pick "Yahoo Mail" from the dropdown, enter your username, and it will do the rest.

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/geary/

Answer (score 0):

I use thunderbird and with no problem with my yahoo account and I did everything in a similar way to my google account.